# Distorted sound coming from Yamaha Electronic Piano

Tags: speakers

I have a Yamaha PSR-E303, and all of a sudden one day when I play a note it comes out warped and transposed several octaves down. The speakers are full of static as well. Unplugging the thing for a while and letting it be fixes the problem, but only for a few seconds, before the sound becomes warped all over again.

This has happened before, but after I let it be for a month, it started to behave correctly again. I suppose the problem returned when I absent-mindedly placed a laptop on top of the thing one day. So to all the electronics-savvy guys in this forum: Is my keyboard doomed?

Answer (score 3):

It's broken.  Very unlikely to be anything to do with putting a laptop on top. Quite likely the power supply, if only on the principle that whenever any electronic item fails, the power supply is the first suspect!   Whether it's worth taking a sub-$200 item to a repair shop is questionable I'm afraid.

Comment: True, but not terribly helpful.

Comment: Helpful, but not terribly optimistic!

Answer (score 2):

I agree w/ Lawrence "House Of"  Payne that it's not worth taking to a repair shop. From your description, it's quite possible that there's a bad solder joint which opens up when the electronics warms up (PC board warping).  If you have a friend who's handy with a soldering iron, ask him/her to open up your KB and see if there's a visible failure point.  If you're getting octave shifts, there's also a good chance that a capacitor has failed in some resonant circuit. Again, this might be located by your electronics-savvy friend.

Comment: unfortunately those types of boards are usually made with micro surface mount components, and are nearly impossible to re-solder with a standard soldering iron.

Comment: @AlphonsoBalvenie most SMDs _can_ be re-soldered with a standard soldering iron – it's tricky, but I wouldn't say “nearly impossible”. However I wouldn't give to much hope that the failure point is easily visible, and just re-soldering all suspicious joints will indeed probably cause more new damage.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely culprit's are -cold or dry solder joints especially in the Audio output section, Shorted electrolyte capacitors, or decentred speaker coils

Answer (score 0):

I recently had issues with my yamaha p115. And after long research found that it is affected by headphones. Probably their cable was causing an induction ,which affected some component in the piano. Static noise that resolves itself after 2 days off. When disconnected from phones, waited 2 days off, brings no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Humidity and wet weather causes my Yammy keybord to blast out a terrible cacophonous mess on certain chord structures. Put a blow heater or refrigerated aircon (not evaporative) at it for a few hours and see if this fixes it.